# Upload large video to server swift using Alamofire

Tags: swift, video, alamofire, avasset, avkit

I have created an application for recording video and upload it to the server, but I meet problem related with huge file size, after some time I get error:

> Task <*****>.<6> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSUnderlyingError=0x280562c70 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <*****>.<6>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("LocalDataTask <6C0A7FA8-C553-4D15-9A2F-8D68E028CE51>.<6>">

How can i upload **Data**(video-data) using **Alamofire** "multipart form-data"?

```
AF.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(fileUrl.url, withName: "file", fileName: "testVideo.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
        },
        to: URLs.COMMENT_URL,
        method: .post,
        headers: headers
        ).responseData { response in
           print(response.response?.description)
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add enough code so we can better understand what you have done so far. Especially the configuration of your request would be usefull. Have you tried setting `timeoutIntervalForRequest`?

Comment: @burnsi no, idk where can u setting it

Comment: Please add enough code so we can better understand what you have done so far. Especially the configuration of your request would be usefull.

Comment: @burnsi I added code to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution is to increase the **default session timeout** by -

```
// Alamofire Session Object 
// Expected in Seconds    
session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5*60
```